# how to set the div to a fixed height using css?

Tags: html, css

i want to set fixed height for the container_two div meaning even though there is only few items in the container_two div there should be some space left at the bottom.

below is my code,

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32px;
    width: 316px;
    height: 225px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container_one {
    height: 101px;
    padding: 16px 6px 16px 22px;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;  
} 

.description {
    height: 42px;
    width: 289px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
 ; 

 .container_two { //this to have a fixed height meaning should always be in 104px and when content 
     //overflows should have a scrollbar
     padding: 16px 0px 16px 10px;
     max-height: 104px;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     overflow-x: hidden;

     & > div {
         margin-right: 4px;
         margin-bottom: 16px;
     }
 }

 .empty_div{ //i want this to be at the end only occupying 16px height
     height: 16px;
     border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
     box-shadow: 0px -6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
     margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;
 }

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container_one">
        <span class="text">sometext</span>
        <div class="description">some big description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_two"> //want to add fixed height to this
    </div>
    <div class="empty_div"/>
</div>
```

with the above code everything works fine. it adds scrollbar if the content in the container_two div overflows and is of not fixed height.

now what i also want is the container_two div should be always of fixed height 104px. also how can i addd boxshadows with 8% opacity for wrapper, container_one, container_two and empty_div.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Change `max-height` to `height` and `overflow-x: hidden;` to `overflow-x: scroll`

Comment: thanks. ho w can i set the opacity for box-shadow to be 8%

Comment: change `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);` to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);`

Answer (score 0):

To keep element at the bottom, it's the easiest to wrap first to containers to one div and than on parent do `justify-content:space-between`

Remove height from parent, because you limit second container to 104px;

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32px;
    width: 316px;
    // height: 225px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 1;
      justify-content: space-between;
}

.container_one {
    height: 101px;
    padding: 16px 6px 16px 22px;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px;  
} 

.description {
    height: 42px;
    width: 289px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

/*  //this to have a fixed height meaning should always be in 104px and when content 
     //overflows should have a scrollbar */
    
 .container_two { 
     padding: 16px 0px 16px 10px;
     height: 104px;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     overflow: auto;

     & > div {
         margin-right: 4px;
         margin-bottom: 16px;
     }
 }

 .empty_div{
     height: 16px;
     border-radius: 0 0 16px 16px;
     box-shadow: 0px -6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
/*      margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px; */
       background-color:red;
       display:block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-holder">
        <div class="container_one">
        <span class="text">sometext</span>
        <div class="description">some big description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_two"> 
            //want to add fixed height to this Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima aliquid modi asperiores qui ipsum labore sequi dicta, maiores iusto, iste officiis sunt provident repudiandae deserunt eveniet natus magni, dolor recusandae! Error quo nobis dolorem. Rerum illo asperiores quae ex quidem vel est pariatur! Sint consectetur veritatis tempore reiciendis incidunt suscipit repellat! Cupiditate voluptate necessitatibus veritatis non libero porro sit odio ad blanditiis perspiciatis inventore voluptates nemo ea sed aliquid beatae repudiandae sequi nam, veniam reiciendis esse eum amet! Temporibus, dicta! Rem soluta esse harum minima saepe velit eos vero amet vel delectus tempore maiores reprehenderit odit, repudiandae beatae dolores voluptatibus?
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="empty_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or if you like you can set empty div's margin top to auto. Without wrapping elements to div